# Location listener working in debug mode but not in compiled APK

Tags: android, eclipse, geolocation

I have a wierd problem in which I have configured a location listener (Google play services fused locations) inside a service. I use the pending intent method (recommended for services).

The thing is that when I'm debugging with Eclipse everything works fine, I receive periodic location updates. But when I compile the apk and run it, the behaviour changes and location  updates is called only once.

Here is the simplified code:

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        //fields

    private PendingIntent locPendingIntent;

    // ====== CONFIGURATION ========

    BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Do this when the system sends the intent
            if (intent.getAction().equals(AppManager.ACTION_LOCATION_READY)) {

                // Called only once on compiled apk. Working fine when debugging


                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                Location loc = (Location) b
                        .get(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);


                if(loc != null) {

                    onLocationChanged(loc); 
                }
            }

        }
    };

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
     * callbacks.
     */
    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null)
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }

    // ======== LIFE CYCLE ========

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInProgress = false;
        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 2.5 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);


        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();

        registerReceiver(locationReceiver, new IntentFilter(AppManager.ACTION_LOCATION_READY));
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if (mLocationClient.isConnected() || mInProgress)
            return START_STICKY;

        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();

        if (!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting()
                && !mInProgress) {
            mInProgress = true;
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    // ===== GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES CALLBACKS ======

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client
     * finishes successfully. At this point, you can request the current
     * location or start periodic updates
     */
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        startListeningForLocations();

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client
     * drops because of an error.
     */
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;
        // Destroy the current location client
        mLocationClient = null;

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
     */
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        mInProgress = false;
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
         * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
         * services activity that can resolve error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

        } else {
            // If no resolution is available, display an error dialog

        }
    }


    private void startListeningForLocations() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(AppManager.ACTION_LOCATION_READY);
        locPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                locPendingIntent);

    }

    // Define the callback method that receives location updates
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // process with location

    }



}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

If anyone needs more details, just ask me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Add the Manifest permissions please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I think I could fix it. 
In my code, I have an Activity and a Service. I was calling the Location Client from the service. In the debug mode it worked fine, but when I bulid the release APK, it didn't work.

I create a method that calls the Location Client and instead calling from the Service, I called it from the activity (at the end of the onServiceConnected method) and it worked.

I hope it work for you.

Best regards, 
Leonardo.